# Apply own CSS to external page

Tags: php, jquery, css

I want to link, into a new tab, an external page and apply to it my own css which change the general layout of this external page. The css is in another server.

Can this be done?

I'm using php, jquery and an Apache server.

I thought in using a php proxy on my server requesting the external page and adding the css but probably, if theres a solution, it will be more efficent.

Thanks!

Comment: depending of what your actual goal is a browser plugin or bookmarklet might be a better idea

Comment: Stefan's idea sounds like a really good solution to your problem, I'd suggest looking into that.

Comment: The idea is to get the external page, resize it, and display it to the users. All this from my mobile web app.
Sorry if I didn't explain fine!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloading the page to your server, applying the CSS and then displaying the page to the user (proxy) is the only way to do this. If the site is insecure and has an exploit you could inject to, you could do it a blackhat way.. but I doubt its that insecure of if anyone here will give you a nasty way to do it + as soon as it was spotted no doubt it would be restored to its original css and the exploit patched.

Think of the security risk if this was possible. CSS is seriously powerful these days, imagine if you could change the CSS on google.com - Fun times :D

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't be done in other way than proxy.

Comment: Or some cross-site scripting... :S

Answer (score 1):

The ability to inject CSS into an embedded iframe (or, more generally, to do *anything* to a child iframe) would open a huge security vulnerability.

Imagine you display an iframe to a webmail service I use, and heavily restyle it so my "compose reply to" page looks like a "confirm password" page from the mail service. When I naively type in my password, it sends my password in an email to the respondent!

You could achieve your desired goal by using a browser plugin or extension. Visiting a web site should require zero trust, but installing an exntesion generally *does* imply some trust from the user, so extensions are given greater freedom than plain web pages.

Note that a server proxy fetch will not send the user's session/auth cookies, so if you are trying to fetch a site that requires a login (e.g., Facebook), you'll only be able to fetch public resources.

Comment: Luckily the site is public. I will try to make or find a php proxy to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve there may be a better approach. If you are planning on distributing it to many users a `broser plugin`, or maybe easier to create, a `UserScript` for Plugins like `Greasemonkey` / Tampermonkey. Another way to do would be creating a `bookmarklet` for the users to click on in their browser bar. Have a look at this here: http://benalman.com/projects/run-jquery-code-bookmarklet/ it's very easy to create.